# Is there a way to add CORS rule to Terraform aws_s3_bucket data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, cors

I have an existing bucket that was not created via Terraform. I'm currently setting a policy on that bucket for additional access rights. I need to add a `cors_rule` to the bucket, but everything I'm finding suggests that you need to create the `resource` in order to add the cors rule. Is there a way to add a `cors_rule` to an existing bucket data source?

- Adding CORS to a bucket that's being created: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#using-cors
- Documentation on the bucket data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"

  # This produces a failure on plan
  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    allowed_origins = [
      "https://example.my-website.com"
    ]
    expose_headers  = [
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "ETag"
    ]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_access" {
  bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_access.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_access" {
  statement {
    sid = "Access"

    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/test"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      data.aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.arn,
      "${data.aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.arn}/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: plan error]

Comment: You should instead configure the bucket in terraform with the cors_rule and then import the bucket into the terraform state.

Comment: @luk2302 appreciate that response, however that's not possible in this case. We have to utilize the bucket that's already existing.

Comment: That is exactly what importing a resource is for.

Comment: I realize it's what it's for, my question is specifically asking "Is there a way?". If importing was an option we would have went with it.

Comment: Then no, you have no alternative. Importing is the solution to your problem. If you intentionally and without good reason disregard the solution designed to solve your problem you are out of luck. Having a data source that mutates something would be terrible anyway and therefore what you want is by design not supported.

Comment: I guess you can always configure a null_resource that runs custom code and perform the S3 api call manually, ugly but possible.

Comment: "If you intentionally and without good reason disregard the solution designed to solve your problem you are out of luck."

No one ever said we were intentionally ignoring a design structure. Sometimes questions are asked after all other normal alternatives have been considered. You have no idea what our business or architectural design constraints are. Once again, I appreciate your responses, in fact I upvoted your first, but I'm simply stating "Its not an option in our case", not that we're ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only modify resources that are managed by terraform, not resources brought in as a data source. What you can do is create a resource for your bucket, and then import the existing bucket:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket my-bucket
```

The import command will give you a list of all properties set on the bucket. For properties you don't want to manage with terraform, use the `ignore` argument on the lifecycle block.

Comment: Unfortunately in our case this may not be possible with our current approach. I do appreciate the clarification though that this is not a possibility as I had described. Thank you!

Comment: Yep. There are a lot of useful tricks for hybrid terraform/manual workflows, but you still hit some hard walls if terraform doesn't get to be in charge. Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

You are in so much luck. Just today / yesterday version 4.0.0 of the AWS provider was released.
That new provider version refactored a lot in regards to S3 bucket handling. You now have a standalone [`s3_bucket_cors_configuration`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_cors_configuration) resource instead of CORS settings directly on the `aws_s3_bucket` resource. That means you can now configure the CORS settings (and many others settings) without actually having the bucket itself in your state.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["PUT", "POST"]
    allowed_origins = ["https://s3-website-test.hashicorp.com"]
    expose_headers  = ["ETag"]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }

  cors_rule {
    allowed_methods = ["GET"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
  }
}
```

The only caveat is that you would need to upgrade to 4.0.0 of the AWS provider with all the breaking changes that come with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "GET"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
    expose_headers  = []
  }
}
```

This works for me with version 3.7